# What are the tradeoffs of using the generalized $f$-median?

Tags: mean, median, generalization

The [generalized f-mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean) is a generalization of multiple estimators, and even generalizes the [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean).

For some [invertible function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) $f$, and $k$-dimensional vector, it is given as:

$$M_f(\vec{x}) \triangleq f^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k) \right)$$

It would serve a similar purpose to define a (possibly more robust) generalized $f$-median.

$$\mathcal{M}_f(\vec{x}) \triangleq f^{-1} \left( \text{median} \left( f(x_k) \right) \right)$$

What are the tradeoffs of using the generalized $f$-median vs the generalized $f$-mean?

Comment: Isn't your "generalized $f$-median" identical to the median?  If not, then please explain what your notation "$\mathcal{M}(f(x_k))$" is intended to signify.

Comment: @whuber If $f$ is the identity function then they are the same, but I see what you mean about the notation. I will improve it.

Comment: When $f$ is strictly invertible they appear to be identical, apart from the usual issues with defining medians when $n$ is an even number.

Comment: I tried a quick Monte Carlo of $\sqrt(\text{median}  (x_k^2))$ where $k=100$ and $X$ was drawn from a standard normal, and they turned out to be different values. I think you're on to something about choice of $f$ that will preserve the order of the values leads to an invariant.

Comment: Of course they will be different values, because the square is not invertible on the support of a Normal variable.  But when $f$ is not invertible, it's not terribly useful for defining any measure of central tendency, is it?

Comment: @whuber Not for all choices of distribution, no. I think the [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) motivates a general case of specific aggregation functions that are sometimes useful.